# Intrinsic and extrinsic properties of sets

Tags: differential-geometry, set-theory, formal-languages

Can a distinction between *intrinsic* and *extrinsic* properties of general sets

a) be defined rigorously and

b) be used fruitfully? (References?)

An intrinsic property of a set $M$ is supposed to be about (the) elements contained in $M$, an extrinsic property is supposed to be about (the) sets containing $M$.

Prototypical examples of intrinsic properties $P$ of a set $X$ are given by formulas of the form

$$P(X) :\equiv \forall x\ x\in X\Rightarrow \phi(x)$$

or

$$P(X) :\equiv \exists x\ x\in X\wedge \phi(x)$$

Prototypical examples of extrinsic properties $P$ of a set $x$ are given by formulas of the form

$$P(x) :\equiv \forall X\ \phi(X) \Rightarrow x \in X$$

or

$$P(x) :\equiv \exists X\ \phi(X) \wedge x \in X$$

> (How) can these examples be subsumed under a general definition?

**Side note:** We find the [intrinsic/extrinsic dichotomy in differential geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry#Intrinsic_versus_extrinsic). Is it defined rigorously at least here? And in which "specialized" fields else - other than set theory?

Comment: Your question "is it defined rigorously at least here" seems to imply that the dichotomy in differential geometry is not fully rigorous.  This is not the case: the dichotomy is fully rigorous.  Intrinsic properties of a surface are those that are independent of its isometric imbedding into Euclidean space, such as its Gaussian curvature.

Comment: I didn't want to imply that - quite the contrary!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a nontrivial "extrinsic" property (of sets) that's not just an indirect way to state an intrinsic one?

Comment: You mean: All sets (which we can talk about) are defined intrinsically, finally? There's no other way? (I have an example in mind - not fully spelled out, yet - but probably I will come to the conclusion, that it's spurious.)

Comment: I am not sure. Within one set-theoretic universe, each set is of course defined completely by its members, so in that sense everything would be "intrinsic". On the other hand, an argument could be made that even "natural number" is extrinsic, if we define that as "is a member of every inductive set".

Comment: @Hans: there is a useful distinction between "internal" and "external" sets in analysis over the hyperreals but I am not sure this is what you are looking for.